# Add all jars in a repository as dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, repository, dependency-management

I have a savant repository in my project and I want to add all of the jars contained within the repo to IntelliJ's depenedcies list. I can add the jars one at a time, but I want to be able to add them all at once.

Is there a way to add all the jars found within all the directories/subdirectories?

***Details:** IntelliJ 12*

***Update:** I can not change the repository structure, it is auto populated when ant builds.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding jars from a directory is supported, but not recursively, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-40818).

Comment: There is a workaround provided by Daniel Brenzel in the link. Here are the details:

-> go to .idea/lib/*yourLib*.xml
-> add the folowing line <jarDirectory url="**file://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib**" -> recursive="true" /> in the library tag

This works seamlessly

Comment: @SvenPlath For me, that line was in .idea/[project name].iml. Then I had to restart IntelliJ for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add all jars in a folder.
You have to create a library and select option: "Attach file or directories" and the select a directory.
This way even a future changes to the directory will be visible.

Comment: Yes, but that only works for a single directory, not a directory full of nested subdirectories that contain jars.