# Add all sub-directories JARs into dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a folder with multiple sub-directories, which all have a JAR file in each of them. This is a simplified structure of the files:

```
lib/
|
|__lib1/
|  |_version1/
|  | |_lib1-1.0.jar
|  |_version2/
|  | |_lib1-2.0.jar
|
|__lib2/
|  |_version1/
|  | |_lib2-1.0.jar
|  |_version2/
|  | |_lib2-2.0.jar
```

Now, I would like to add all of the JARs recursively into the dependencies list inside of the Project Strucutre (in IntelliJ IDEA 14).

Is there a quick way of achieving this without having to expand all directories and select the artifacts manually?

Comment: I don't know of a way to recursively add JARs, but if you add a directory IntelliJ will add all files in that directory.  How many folders do you have?

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On IntelliJ 2019.2

1. Open the "Project Structure" (Command-;)
2. Select "Libraries" from the left list
3. Push the + button to add a library, navigate to directory or your
   choice and click "Open". When IntelliJ asks to identify the category
   of files of the directory, pick "Jar Directory".
4. Click "OK" and close this window.
5. Locate the .idea/libraries/system.xml file in your project and open
   it.
6. Locate the  entry for the folder you just added as a
   library and change the 'recursive' argumument from false to true.
7. Save the file

As soon as you save IntelliJ will recurse through the directories and add all the jars it can find to the entry of your library in the project navigator.

Answer (score 6):

In your project home directory, there exists an .iml file add this under 
`<library> : <jarDirectory url="url to the folder containing jars" recursive = "true">`

Worked for me.

Comment: wow this is like some insider information.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965016/add-all-jars-in-a-repository-as-dependencies-in-intellij) from 2 years ago, adding JARs recursively from a directory is not currently supported in IntelliJ, although there is request for this feature to be added in a future release.

Your question is not a duplicate because the post cited above is IntelliJ version 12 and you are using version 14.  If anyone has evidence that this feature has made it into version 14 please add a comment to this answer.

Comment: This sadly does not seem to have been implemented. I am going to mark this as answer since this is not currently supported in IntelliJ IDEA 14 (and 15 EAP too).